# How to apply Serializable attribute globally?

Tags: c#, attributes, serializable

I have to apply [Serializable()] attribute for all classes, but I want to know is there any way to make classes Serializable globally instead of applying this attribute individually for all classes?

Comment: Why? This attribute is not mandatory for a class to be serializable in general. It is a marker for some mechanisms, like remoting, binary formatter or soap formatter. It has *nothing* to do with XML or JSON serialization in general.

Comment: @ZorgoZ thank you, because of using session in sql server mode, I have to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way of applying this globally - you'd have to visit each type and add the attribute.

However: applying this globally is a *really, really* bad idea. Knowing exactly what you're serializing, when, and why is *really important* - whether this is for session-state, primary persistence, cache, or any other use-case. Statements like

> I have to apply `[Serializable()]` attribute for all classes

tells me that you *are not* currently in control of what you are storing.

Additionally, since `[Serializable]` maps (usually) to `BinaryFormatter`, it is important to know that there are a *lot* of ways (when using `BinaryFormatter`) in which it is possible to accidentally drag unexpected parts of your model into the serialized data. The most notorious of these is "events", but: there are others.

When I see this type of question, what I envisage is that you're using types from your main data model as the thing that you are putting into session-state, but frankly: *this is a mistake* - and leads to questions like this. Instead, the far more maneagable approach is to create a separate model that exists *purely for this purpose*:

- it *only* has the data that you need to have available in session
- it is marked `[Serializable]` if your provider needs that - or whatever other metadata is needed *for the sole purpose for which it exists*
- it *does not* have any events
- it doesn't involve any tooling like ORM contexts, database connections etc
- ideally it is immutable (to avoid confusion over what happens if you make changes locally, which can otherwise sometimes behave differently for in-memory vs persisted storage)
- just plain simple basic objects - very easy to reason about
- can be iterated *separately* to your main domain objects, so you don't have any unexpected breaks because you changed something innocent-looking in your domain model and it broke the serializer